# what is the good way to listen RSS every time and get updates in real time?

Tags: java, azure, rss

I have server program who send notifications to the client. 
at the server side I used pull request every 15 minutes to RSS files of news url and check if exists new data to send to the client. 
I am searching about way something like open stream or something else between my server and RSS url to get every moment new data.
does it possible? 
other thing. which azure cloud service is the best service for that? 
(currently I used timerFunction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure logic  app would be the most optimum to use in this scenario, good things that there is a build connector available for RSS feed from Azure Logic App.

This connector is available in the following products and regions:

[image]

**Here is the general limit for the connector:**

Maximum content length (in MB)                    5

Polling interval of the RSS trigger (in seconds)    1800

**Throttling Limit**

API calls per connection    100 60 seconds

You can read about this more in details in below doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/rss/#list-all-rss-feed-items

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-rss

Hope it helps.